# I got following errors while implementing cluster_visualizer

Tags: python

I wanted to implement cure clustering to my dataset.

following codes ran without problem

```
cure_instance = cure(X, 2)
cure_instance.process()
clusters = cure_instance.get_clusters()
```

I got an issue with the following code:

```
visualizer = cluster_visualizer_multidim()
visualizer.append_clusters(clusters, X)
visualizer.show()
```

[image]

as suggested including `all()` shows following error;

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()